# How can I retrieve sparse set of values for a given partial rowkey?

Tags: hbase

Given that I have a rowkey which consists of a customer and date, `customer_timestamp`, how might I perform a `Get` operation which produces a search with the given sparse values.

e.g. consider I have the following:

```
| rowkey       | cust/first_name | cust/last_name | cust/address   |
| ------------ | --------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 012-20170701 |                 |                | 12 Some Street | 
| 012-20170301 | Jenny           |                |                |
| 012-20170101 | Jane            | Doe            |                |
```

How can I perform a `Get` for `012-` which returns the following without having to do a scan from the prefix, or; is a scan the only solution?

```
| rowkey       | cust/first_name | cust/last_name | cust/address   |
| ------------ | --------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 012          | Jenny           | Doe            | 12 Some Street |
```

Answer (score 0):

In HBase get will only return one row.
In your case you want multiple rows on from a range on the rowkey. In this case you should do a scan with `scan 't1', {STARTROW=>"012-",STOPROW=>"012-~"}`

Comment: Ta, I think a simpler solution would be to take the date out of the rowkey and use the cell version instead?

Comment: Thinking about that, I don’t think that’s a great idea as I would potentially want several hundred versions. Instead, what would be the cost associated using a scan approach where I would need to scan through until I have all sparse values where one cell value may not be present for several hundred or thousand rows?

Comment: Can you provide an example for the sparse values?

Comment: My example is shown in the first example where cell values will only be set where they changed. What I want to do is flatten all values since a given date, but do it over a large set of customers. E.g. what are all of the changes for all customers sincex